# Messenger bot undefined messaged

Tags: facebook-messenger, chatbot, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I am creating new Messenger chatbot for my FB page but when I write message from my FB page to someone then it shows "undefined" messaged notification. Do you know where is problem (FB page configuration or chatbot code)? This problem is only on Facebook, Messenger is OK.

I am creating my chatbot in PHP (Symfony2 framework).

Thank you!
[undefined messaged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d02WF.png)

Comment: Add more information

Comment: I just noticed this error, 5 minutes ago, although I have been developing in the bot for over 3 weeks, are you using node.js?

Comment: No PHP, where is problem in node?

Comment: I don't know, but I am getting the same thing as you: "undefined sent you a message"

Comment: Messenger is OK, but problem in only on Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you used to make your chatbot, but if you used node.js, undefined typically means that you declared an empty variable and have yet to assign it a value. I believe the same is the case for PHP, but I'm not 100% sure.